# What stopping metric to chose to optimize 'sensitivity' for a GBM in H2O?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, r, cross-validation, gbm

I am predicting a disease and want to get the highest possible sensitivity score for the predicted values on my validation and test set.

**What stopping metric can be used to optimize the sensitivity score on validation set?**

I have about 400 observations. The response variable is binary (0/1) and I have 40 predictor variables.

My current set-up uses AUC as stopping metric.

```
df <- as.h2o(df)
split <- h2o.splitFrame(data=df, ratios=c(0.6, 0.2)) # split 60, 20, 20%
train <- h2o.assign(split[[1]], "train.hex") # 60%
valid <- h2o.assign(split[[2]], "valid.hex") # 20%
test <- h2o.assign(split[[3]], "test.hex") # 20%

x <- setdiff(names(df), "disease")
y <- "disease"

gbm <- h2o.gbm(
  x = x, 
  y = y, 
  training_frame = train, 
  validation_frame = valid,
  ntrees = 10000,                                                            
  learn_rate=0.01,     
  # Stopping parameters                                                    
  stopping_rounds = 5, stopping_tolerance = 1e-4, stopping_metric = "AUC", 
  sample_rate = 0.8,                                                       
  col_sample_rate = 0.8,                                                   
  seed = 1234,                                                             
  nfolds = 50,
  score_tree_interval = 10                                                 
)
h2o.auc(h2o.performance(gbm, valid = TRUE))
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with H2O, but can you use the [F1 score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score)?

Comment: @Jurgy The F1 score is based on the recall & specificity. I'm, at this, only interested in optimizing the recall(=sensitivity).

Comment: Optimizing for just sensitivity is a bad idea because an always positive approach will lead to maximum sensitivity: S = TP / (TP + FN), with always positive FN = 0 so you get S = TP / TP = 1.

Answer (score 1):

One solution to make the recall more important whitout getting to the problem mentionned by @Jurgy is to use $F_\beta$, a modified version of $F_1$ where recall is considered $\beta$ time more important. As seen here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score, $F_\beta$ can be formulated both in terms of recall/precision, and in term of type I /type II error. You then need to select a $\beta$ based on how much recall is more important to you... this can be done by considerations on the costs of type I vs the cost of type II errors.